# React-Native BLE Manager works on Android but not IOS (could not find service with uuid)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

I coded a JavaScript react-native project and ran it on my **Android phone & iPhone**.

***It works on android phone but it doesn't work on iPhone.***

- I am Using **BLE manager** Library.
- I can find & connect devices using ios and android.
- I can subscrible and send data using anroid.
- I know that there are no mistakes on code because it works on Android.
- ***I can't start notifications and send data using the same react native project on IOS***
- ***I think it is because of BLE manager library but don't know how to solve it***

It works perfectly on android. As shown below.

```
            ANDROID IMAGE(Console below Code Top)
```

[image]

Then I uploaded the same project on my iPhone. I get the following UUID mismatch. Code is the same but can't communicate.

```
             IOS IMAGE (Console Top Code Below)
```

[image]

**Note LightBlue Info:**

If Someone can tell me what to write on ID,ServiceUUID,CharUUID It would be lovely.

[image: LightBlue Info]

---

---

---

***UPDATE******

I tried this:

As seen on the picture below, I connected to device using ID, But can't find service with UUID

[image]

Comment: If `4c:24:98:13:37:08` is the device MAC address, then this won't work on iOS.  iOS apps have no access to the device MAC address.  You would typically discover your peripheral by looking for the service it is advertising.

Comment: I tried [link](https://ibb.co/8007VHR) Can you tell me what to type on Device Id, ServiceUUID, CharUUID. I'm trying stuff if I found I'll tell

Comment: On iOS the identifier that you get for a peripheral is unique for that peripheral on that iOS device. No other iOS device will see that same identifier for that peripheral. You can download the LightBlue app from the App Store to discover the services advertised by your peripheral if you don't know what they are

Comment: [LightBlueImage](http://example.com)  I tried diffirent values, if you can tell ID ServiceUUID CharUUID
Like:


Id:"" ServiceUUID"" CharUUID ""

I would be great much love

Comment: That image link doesn't work

Comment: I updated the question if you check it I would be so happy.

Comment: It looks like it is a temperature sensor. It is advertising service `FFE0`. That is the service you will need to scan for to discover the peripheral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248594/discussion-between-huseyin-safa-unlu-and-paulw11).